# ASP.NET MVC eCommerce solutions (either commercial or open source)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, e-commerce, ninject, entity-framework-5

Okay, so we have a development infrastructure that utilizes the following:
1. MVC 4 (Razor views)
2. Entity Framework 5 code first
3. Ninject

What I'm looking for are eCommerce solutions that are as close as possible to our existing infrastructure in hopes of integrating as seamlessly as possible.

I've looked at many, many options including:
1. NopCommerce
2. Magelia
3. dashCommerce
4. DotShoppingcart

So far NopCommerce and Magelia (NopCommerce especially), seem to be the closest I can find.  I'm looking for suggestions of other eCommerce solutions that might better integrate with our existing infrastructure mentioned above.  Cost is really not an issue, so it can be open source or commercial.

Any and all suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks

Nick

Comment: I do not undestand why people vote down such questions. I have exactly the same need and I found it very useful. So - I vote up ! List of products that you have provided coincides my list, so at least it is confirmation that these are "the solutions". Magelia can be plugged-in to Orchard, which makes it for my project more attractive, but it's only first estimation.

Comment: i started working mvc with nopcommerce first, it's a good best practice for people who want to start directly from a project.
Nopcommerce is your best ever solution.

Answer (score 3):

try this http://virtocommerce.com/ and enterprise open source ecommerce solutions using the latest technology of .Net

Answer (score 2):

Nick,

I haven't had a chance to evaluate it yet, as I literally just came across it right before finding your post (I'm doing a similar search for my company,) but you might consider  http://merchanttribe.codeplex.com/

As I say, I haven't even looked at the code yet, but they have an open-source MVC eCommerce platform.

Drew

Answer (score 0):

Nick,

You can also check [Cart42](http://www.cart42.com) ([GitHub](https://github.com/eStream/Cart42)). It utilizes ASP.NET MVC with Razor views, Entity Framework 5 with code-first. However for DI it uses StructureMap rather than Ninject.